# JButton in GridBagLayout in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I am learning swing from past week, I have some issue with GridBagConstraints to put one button in top left corner but all other buttons in default in GridBagConstraints ?

I am using code that like not original but states the problem

```java
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    JButton menu = new JButton("Menu"), button = new JButton("Puzzle");

    GridBagConstraints gbc1 = new GridBagConstraints(), gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();

    private void setup()
    {
        gbc1.anchor   = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_START;
        gbc2.anchor   = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbc2.weightx  = 1.0;
        gbc2.weighty  = 1.0;
    }

    public MyPanel()
    {
        this.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        this.setup();
        this.button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 140));
        this.add(menu, gbc1);
        this.add(button, gbc2);
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Test extends JFrame
{
    public Test()
    {
        this.setTitle("Test");
        this.setContentPane(new MyPanel());
        this.setResizable(false);
        this.setSize(800, 600);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new Test());
    }
}
```

output

[image: output]

I want menu is top corner.

I read from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#:%7E:text=GridBagLayout%20is%20one%20of%20the,necessarily%20have%20the%20same%20height.) but i did not understand this Could you please explain GridBagConstraints for how to do that.

I Hope that problem is clear to understand, if not please let me know in comments.

EDIT:

@camickr suggestion works but a little problem, the Puzzle Button is not in extract center.

Thanks.

Comment: Varaible names *Bmenu, Bpuzzle" should NOT start with an upper case character. Follow Java naming conventions. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for your time and reply, Could you please see updated post, does it is understandable ?

Comment: I gave suggestion in my answer. You have not implemented any of the suggestions. In addition to the suggestions already given you will need to use the "gridx/gridy" constraints. So you need to reread the tutorial and look at the details for all the constraints that are needed.

Comment: I gave suggestion in my answer. You have not implemented any of the suggestions by setting the constraints on the second button. In addition to the suggestions already given you will need to use the "gridx/gridy" constraints. So you need to reread the tutorial and look at the details for all the constraints that are needed. If you still have problems, then update the MRE showing the code that uses the constraints I suggested.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for your suggestion it works but a little problem the Puzzle button is not in extract center, could you please tell how to solve that. Thanks.

Comment: @camickr I solved it but put gridx and gridy to 0 in center component, but i did not completely understand the setttings could you please explain why that happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default the GridBagLayout will display all the components centered horizontally and vertically, unless one of the components has a weightx/weighty value not equal to 0. Then that component will fill the extra space in the frame.

So if you want one component at the "top/left" and one in the "center", you need to:

1. use the "anchor" constraint. It will be different for both components.
2. the component in the center will need to use the "weightx/weighty" constraints.

However, an easer solution might be to use a combination of panels with different layout managers.

For example:

```
JPanel menuPanel = new JPanel( new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT) );
menuPanel.add(menuButton);

JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel( new GridBagLayout() );
centerPanel.add(puzzle, new GridBagConstraints());

frame.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

So now the "top" of the frame will contain a panel with components displayed from the left and the "center" of the frame will contain your puzzle centered in the remaining space of the frame.

Edit:

> I solved it but put gridx and gridy to 0 in center component, but i did not completely understand the setttings

Well I mentioned that you would need to use the gridx/gridy constraints. You should always use those constraints as it is very obvious what grid you want to add the component to. The examples from the tutorial always specify those values.

Using gridx/gridy both equal to 0, does not really make sense. The effect is that you have two components trying to share the same grid.

Remove the setResizable(false) statement and shrink the size of the frame to see how the button repositions itself.

It is not normal that two components share the same grid. Normally you would have the menu on the first row and the button on the second row. This will center the button horizontally in the frame and vertically in the space below the menu.
What you are doi

Comment: See edit. Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.